# Clone code form gitlab by public ssh keys always ask me to enter password?

Tags: git, ssh

I have put my public keys to my gitlab server profile.When I clone code from server by ssh , it always ask me to enter password and I don't known the password.
When this happen? How to solve it???

Comment: Probably you have set a passphrase for the SSH private key, or you're not cloning via SSH at all.

Comment: How does your URL look like? Are the private keys in the right location?